# run-time 2737 when connecting OLE Object (Word file) who is inside OneDrive Folder

Tags: ms-access, onedrive, ole

I'm developing a solution based on Word and Access.
In an Access mask, the user click a command and a Word file is automacilly created and inserted in a BoundObjectFrame via  the following command:

```
With OleDoc
      .Class = "Word.Document"
      .OLETypeAllowed = acOLELinked
      .SourceDoc = strFullNameFile
      .Action = acOLECreateLink
End With
```

Everything is fine if the file named strFullNameFile is in a normal folder on my computer. But if is in a subfolder inside my OneDrive folder in my computer, I get a
Run-time error 2737
Impossible to find  file with OLE object linked...

Do you have any idea why?
Thanks, Lauro

Comment: Maybe have to download from OneDrive to local folder and connect there.

Comment: I save in my local folder that is inside my local OneDrive folder

Comment: Your "local OneDrive" folder is mapped to the OneDrive cloud? That is not a folder on the computer drive.

Comment: What do you mean? From cmd and dos command I find my "local OneDrive" folder.

Comment: Isn't OneDrive cloud storage hosted by Microsoft? So your files are really stored on some remote server drive storage. Just because you can map a drive letter to that remote location doesn't mean the files are located on your computer's hard drive. Same as mapping a drive to LAN file server.

Comment: Thanks June7. I tried to share what I have achieved thanks to your suggestion in the following answer

Comment: Hi, I have more details on this problem and I would like to have some more help. I can't accept there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path with subfolder too.
It's searching the file in main folder.

Comment: I'm passing the full name in both cases